# RDLC report not showing up inside a user control

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls, rdlc

I am trying to show a rdlc report inside a user control. The problem is that it does not show when I run the project.

***Before running the project I can see it in xaml designer.***

[image: Before Running Project in xaml Desginer]

***After Running project:***
[image]

Here is my code:

***Report User Control:***

```
<UserControl x:Class="CPOSApplication.UserControls.Reports.ReportViewer"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300" Background="#FFFFFFFF"
         xmlns:repview="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms;assembly=Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms">
<Grid>
    <WindowsFormsHost x:Name="winform" Background="White" Visibility="Visible">
        <repview:ReportViewer  BackColor="white"  x:Name="salesReportViewer"/>
    </WindowsFormsHost>
</Grid>
```

***Another UserControl where it is being used:***

```
<UserControl x:Class="CPOSApplication.UserControls.Reports.SalesReport"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         xmlns:uc="clr-namespace:CPOSApplication.UserControls.Reports"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="800" d:DesignWidth="900">
<Grid Style="{DynamicResource GridsCustomStyle}" x:Name="SearchShelfGri">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="100" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Border  Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Style="{DynamicResource SearchGridHeaderBorder}">
        <DockPanel Grid.Row="0">
            <Label x:Name="GridLabel" Style="{DynamicResource HeadingLabelsCustomStyle}" Content="Sales Report-:"/>
        </DockPanel>
    </Border>
    <uc:ReportViewer x:Name="salesReport"  Grid.Column="0" Background="White" Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,0"/>
    <uc:FilterSalesReport x:Name="filterShelf"  Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Background="AliceBlue" Width="300" Padding="2,0,0,0" Margin="0,0"/>
</Grid>
```

***It's .cs File***

```
public partial class SalesReport : UserControl
{
    public SalesReport()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        salesReport.salesReportViewer.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;
        salesReport.salesReportViewer.LocalReport.ReportPath = @"C:\Users\Safi\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\CPOS\CPOS\CPOSApplication\Reports\QuarterSaleInvoiceReport.rdlc";
        salesReport.salesReportViewer.RefreshReport();
        salesReport.salesReportViewer.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = "CPOSApplication.Reports." + ReportType.QuarterSaleInvoice.ToString() + "Report.rdlc";
        salesReport.salesReportViewer.RefreshReport();

    }
}
```

Comment: Try to get some UI properties of your usercontrol in the code, like visibility, width... and see what those properties give you. If they seem valid, you know it's still there. Is it possible to add code where you initiatie the call to perform this action?

Answer (score 0):

//in your CS file, create this method

```
    public void GenReport()
    {
        YourReportViewfname.LocalReport.ReportPath = @"paste Your RDLC Location";

        YourClass rptclsProp01 = new YourClass();

        var data = rptclsProp01.YourList();
        ReportDataSource dataSource = new ReportDataSource("YourDataSet", data);
        YourReportViewfname.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
        YourReportViewfname.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(dataSource);
        YourReportViewfname.RefreshReport();
        YourReportViewfname.Show();
    }
```

//then Button Click event, just call the method

```
        this.YourUCfnam.salesReport.GenReport();
```

//hope that report will show